# Properties not loading for single project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have a Winforms project and checked in both VS 2015 and VS 2019. Properties for controls are not loading for just a single project in both versions. I have tried to re-create the solution but it remains the same.

[image]

Edit:
Hi, I found the problem, I used this control which cause lag. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91387/Painting-Your-Own-Tabs-Second-Edition-2

When I opened the form that was using this control, it was flickering in VS designer and lagged the whole VS interface. If anybody can help to fix this?

Comment: Is it a generic toolStripContainer ? Can you add some background information about the used classes ?

Comment: What is the name of the control you are using? Is this a 3rd party control?